# How to make second container?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I recently started programming in flutter. I want to add second container in my app.  When i duplicate the container code in my class, i get an error `dead code` in this part of the text.  Could you please help me with adding the second container?

```
  NewsBoxFavourit(this._num);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyFormState();
}
class MyFormState extends State {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Выполнено кругов'),
          TextFormField(validator: (value){if (value.isEmpty) return 'Введите количество кругов';}),



        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewsBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _title;
  final String _text;
  String _imageurl;
  int _num;

  NewsBox(this._title, this._text, {String imageurl, int num = 0,}) {
    _imageurl = imageurl;
    _num = num;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_imageurl != null && _imageurl != '') return new Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 100.0,
        child:  Row(children: [
           Image.network(_imageurl, width: 100.0, height: 100.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
           Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
             Text('Дата'),
               TextFormField(validator: (value){if (value.isEmpty) return 'Введите количество кругов';}),

             Expanded(child: Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
          ]
          ))
          ),  NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)

        ])
    );

    return Container(
        color: Colors.black12,
        height: 100.0,
        child: Row(children: [
          Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child: Column(children: [
             Text(_title, style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),

            Expanded(child: Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
          ]
          ))
          ),   NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)
        ])
    );
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if (_imageurl != null && _imageurl != '') return new Container(
          color: Colors.black12,
          height: 100.0,
          child:  Row(children: [
            Image.network(_imageurl, width: 100.0, height: 100.0, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
            Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child:  Column(children: [
              Text('Дата'),
              TextFormField(validator: (value){if (value.isEmpty) return 'Введите количество кругов';}),

              Expanded(child: Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
            ]
            ))
            ),  NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)

          ])
      );
    return Container(color:Colors.black12,
    height: 100.0,
    child: Row(children: [
      Expanded(child:  Container(padding:  EdgeInsets.all(5.0), child: Column(children: [
        Text(_title, style:  TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),

        Expanded(child: Text(_text, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.justify,))
      ]
      ))
      ),   NewsBoxFavourit(_num,)
    ])
    );

  }
}
```

Please, explain why it does not execute the code? How to make second Conteiner? What i need to do with dead code?

Comment: why there are 2 build methods in `NewsBox`?

Comment: your codes are a little dirty. Need to share more clear codes. In addition, seems like a problem with 2 build method in NewsBox

Answer (score 0):

Flutter does not work like what your code is showing. Your `NewsBox` custom widget can only have 1 build method. If you want 2 containers in a single widget then try using Column, Row, Stack and many other widgets. These can be found under the Multi-child layout widgets in the [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/layout). I'd assume you'd want the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget though I do not know what design you'd like to achieve.